# 2021 M1 Max MacBook Pro: Left Speaker Popping/Crackling/Sound Distortion. Sound is also very right-heavy. macOS 14.3.1

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, speakers

This seemed to be a massive issue a couple of years or so ago, as it kept popping up on Reddit's MBP sub. Then it must have been fixed in an update (intimating that it's software-related), but it seems to be back again for me, and I can't think that I've done anything which might have caused it.

see https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookpro/comments/u9xp3y/new_2021_macbook_pro_14_and_16_speaker_issue/) then it seemed to go away as I stopped reading posts about it.

I can't post to Apple's own forum, as the phone I used for 2FA has been stolen (and I'm too skint to replace it).

```
[2021 M1 Max MacBook Pro Left Speaker Sound Distortion Issue][1]
```

This is the issue (no comments about my tastes in music, please!).

M1 Max MBP Left Speaker Sound Distortion Issue (recorded via Voice Memos on a 4th generation iPad Pro).

The Mac is clean, it's not been dropped or handled roughly. I've shaken it (very gently) and I can't hear that there's anything which has come loose.
Unfortunately, my current circumstances mean that I am unable to get to an Apple Store (annoying as it's still under AppleCare+).

Please keep any fixes simple, my brain is broken.

If there's nobody here who can assist, could you point me to a better place to post...? I miss the old Mac Rumours forum where people actually genuinely wanted to help people.
I've cleaned it, it's been restarted in Safe Mode. I've not installed any new software.

There was a thing originally where people stated that it was being caused by Rosetta, and that apps which were natively Intel were to blame. I'm not running any Intel-native apps (at least I don't think I am).

Is there any software I can use to at least lessen it (because it's really, ***REALLY*** annoying)...? I don't have much money, so would need to be cheap or free.

Thank you

Comment: Do you hear the crackling when you plug in a pair of headphones/earbuds?

Comment: FWIW, I've never had this on my M1 Pro 16". I would do the usual troubleshooting: test Safe Boot mode; test a brand new user account; use Activity Monitor to see if the CPU or RAM is hitting red. Is it all audio output, all the time? Try changing the sample rate to 44.1 kHz; or creating a Multi-output audio device, which only includes the built-in speakers in Audio MIDI Setup.app. But I'd want to get hardware ruled out.